# How to install Algo VPN remaining dependencies Terminal

Tags: python, terminal

I am trying to install the remaining dependencies for Algo VPN using Terminal via step 4 on https://github.com/trailofbits/algo

I believe I was in the folder above the one I was supposed to be in the last time I ran this, and I used the sudo command. So now I think there is an issue with the permissions that I don't know how to fix. It could be a simple fix, but I just don't want to create any more mess with the permissions.

Here is the code that I am running in terminal

```
$ python -m virtualenv --python=`which python2` env &&
    source env/bin/activate &&
    python -m pip install -U pip virtualenv &&
    python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I receive the error -

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/env
env: /Users/mark/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/virtualenv.py: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code that I was using to try to install the remaining dependencies.

```
$ python -m virtualenv --python=`which python2` env &&
source env/bin/activate &&
python -m pip install -U pip virtualenv &&
python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

When I ran this about a week ago and I was able to get it to work and I believe it looked like this. I thought I just left it with no version of Python believing it would default to the current version and I believe it worked.

```
$ python -m virtualenv --python=env &&
source env/bin/activate &&
python -m pip install -U pip virtualenv &&
python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

So I decided to try

```
$ python -m virtualenv --python=python2.7 env &&
source env/bin/activate &&
python -m pip install -U pip virtualenv &&
python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

And it worked.

---

So maybe I had an extra space so it looked like

```
$ python -m virtualenv --python= env &&
source env/bin/activate &&
python -m pip install -U pip virtualenv &&
python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

or maybe I did in fact need the python2.7

```
$ python -m virtualenv --python=python2.7 env &&
source env/bin/activate &&
python -m pip install -U pip virtualenv &&
python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I will note that I used terminal to show show hidden files by

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
```

and then I navigated in Finder to

/Users/mark/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/virtualenv.py

and it showed that I had the correct permissions. So I don't think had to do with using sudo previously.